# R `dev.new()` freezes

Tags: r, graphics, freeze

this just started to occur: when I type the command `dev.new()`, the window stays frozen, and I can't `Ctrl+c` to stop it. I have to kill the `R` process in another terminal. I am running 64-bit `CentOS 6.7` and `R 3.2.1`. Here is the output from `sessionInfo()`:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.2.1 (2015-06-18)
Platform: x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: CentOS release 6.7 (Final)
locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.utf8       LC_NUMERIC=C              LC_TIME=en_US.utf8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.utf8     LC_MONETARY=en_US.utf8
 [6] LC_MESSAGES=en_US.utf8    LC_PAPER=en_US.utf8       LC_NAME=C                 LC_ADDRESS=C              LC_TELEPHONE=C
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.utf8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C

attached base packages:
[1] graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  stats     methods   base

other attached packages:
[1] ggplot2_1.0.1    data.table_1.9.4 plyr_1.8.3       reshape2_1.4.1   vimcom_0.9-9     setwidth_1.0-4   colorout_1.1-0

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_0.12.0      digest_0.6.8     MASS_7.3-44      chron_2.3-47     grid_3.2.1       gtable_0.1.2     magrittr_1.5     scales_0.3.0
 [9] stringi_0.5-5    proto_0.3-10     tools_3.2.1      stringr_1.0.0    munsell_0.4.2    colorspace_1.2-6
```

Has anybody come across this issue? Perhaps of relevance, but I was able to use a GUI application that creates plot devices as a `cairoDevice`, with no issues.

---

EDIT: A bit more info - when running `R --vanilla`, the same behavior occurs. Same with calling `plot` directly (e.g. `plot(rnorm(1e2))`), and making a call to `ggplot`.

---

EDIT 2: in case this wasn't confusing enough, I am able to plot without issue on my home system (where `sessionInfo` gives the same output, aside from some packages loaded via a namespace). I believe the same CentOS packages are installed, as well.

---

EDIT 3: to add a bit more info, in addition to the (`RGtk2`) GUI that I mentioned still works, I can call `Cairo` from the command line directly and plotting works without issue that way. So it seems to be specific to base plotting.

Comment: If you load a clean R session, then run `dev.new()`, it freezes?

Comment: Yes, running `R --vanilla` it will still freeze.

Comment: Did you recently update some CentOS libraries?

Comment: I don't remember if I had this issue on Thursday; if so, then I hadn't done an update since Aug. 7. If not, today I updated several, but I don't see any that could be related. *Maybe* `kmod-nvidia`, `nvidia-x11`, `*vdpau*`, `xcb-util` (but I updated after seeing this `R` issue), and `R-mvtnorm`. All others are unrelated.

Comment: Try the upgrade to version 3.2.2 if you can.

Comment: Is it available for CentOS 6 yet? I don't see it on a `yum` search.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem on SL6.7. This is not a R problem but rather the xorg-x11-server-Xorg update crashed it.

Just downgrade the package and restart your X-session and you can plot again.

~$ yum downgrade http://ftp.scientificlinux.org/linux/scientific/6.6/x86_64/updates/security/xorg-x11-server-Xorg-1.15.0-26.sl6.x86_64.rpm

To make it permanent disable the upgrade of the package in yum.conf

~$ echo "exclude=xorg-x11-server-Xorg" >> /etc/yum.conf

Comment: Hmm, I will try this out. Thanks!

Comment: Awesome, that worked! It's strange though, because I have the newer package installed on 2 other systems without issue. Oh well.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, the issue with R was not really a bug in xorg-x11-server.
Its update (Fix backing store's Always mode) revealed a bug in the X11
module of R. More details can be found in R's bugzilla :

https://bugs.r-project.org/bugzilla3/show_bug.cgi?id=16497
(See comment 5 for details)

A couple of patches to fix the issue have been proposed.